# How can I dump entire ViewModel to View in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Inspite of seeing the model by setting breakpoint, I want to dump each and every object inside the ViewModel to its corresponding View in Action method, so that I can see its properties in the browser.

Is there any direct method for doing this in asp.net MVC just like we have in PHP Zend Framework ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [JSON serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) the model in the view:

```
<pre>
    <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>
</pre>
```

or use XML format if you prefer.

Comment: Hi...  I have put tis in an RaszorView.cshtml, but then it only outputs : <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>  - NOT the object... What am I'm doing wrong. ?