# how to quickly view all ViewModel data in the MVC page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When working in the MVC project, I often want to see the all data of the View Model object that passed through from the controller.

Without having to add break points in the controller code and using watcher, is there a quicker way to see it on the View/Page on the web browser?

In another word, i want to quickly "bind" the view model object to some sort of view control to display all data of the page?

Sorry I'm MVC newbie & hope it makes some sense.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I dump entire ViewModel to View in asp.net MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521493/how-can-i-dump-entire-viewmodel-to-view-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

When creating a view, there is a checkbox ***create a strongly typed view***, from which you can generate create, edit, delete and view forms quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be [MVCScaffolding](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/).
It uses Entity Framework to build out the Controller, View and repository context.

using the nuget Package Console

Install-Package MvcScaffolding

Answer (score 0):

why don't you add a list view to show all the objects . See the tutorial. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/create-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-asp-net-mvc-vb